# How to Display LocalizedString File data?

Tags: iphone, localization

I want to display Localized.string file content at the display time, what is code for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
NSLog(@"Welcome Text: %@", NSLocalizedString(@"YourKey", @""));
```

Your key is name of your key in localized.string file.

Comment: I had tryed this but it returned not file content.

Comment: Please check this tutorial: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/a-simple-localization-example-for-the-iphone